# How to send data between one adapter to another adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually, I have a Recyclerview where has a button and(where I get id with position[from RestAPi call])--->>when the button is clicked I set another recylerview..and now I want to the from the first RecyclerviewAdapter.
**I have already tried global variable**

Here is images [enter image description here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12A-yLnKyVsJhiCQacWoie2PPeiqFQ0lC)

Comment: Add some code of your logic & brief your question.

Comment: Set your 2 Adapter in to 1 adapter onBindViewHolder().

Comment: please check out my screenshot which I have mentioned. screenshoot(2) is the first adpter and the screenshoot(3) is the secondadapter where i want to pass my data.i have tried global veriable but it didn't work,the data was not updated.

Answer (score 0):

> From my previous answer from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134831/accessing-an-adapters-data-via-another-adapter/52136029#52136029) i think you need a `Singleton Pattern` rather than a **Global Variable**

You simply need a `getter` that returns the another `Adapter's` `ArrayList<SingleItemModel>` but the problem you will face is that you need to have the same instance of the `Adapter` from the `Activity` in order to get the populated `ArrayList<Model>`.

> A good workaround is to used Bill Pugh's Singleton in the `Adapter`

```
public class Adapter {

private ArrayList<Model> list;

private Adapter() {}

public static Adapter getInstance() {
    return InstInit.INSTANCE;
}

// Don't forget to set the list (or NPE)
// because we can't argue with a Singleton
public void setList(ArrayList<Model> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

// You can now get the ArrayList
public ArrayList<Model> getList() {
    return list;
}

private static class InstInit {
    private static final Adapter INSTANCE = new Adapter();
}

// Some codes removed for brevity
// Overrided RecyclerView.Adapter Methods
.................

}
```

> Retrieving the `ArrayList` assuming that the following `Adapters` are Singleton

```
AdapterOne a1 = AdapterOne.getInstance();
AdapterTwo a2 = AdapterTwo.getInstance();

ArrayList<Model> a1RetrievedList = a1.getList();
// You don't need to create a new instance
// creating a new instance doesn't make sense
// because you need to repopulate the list
// for the new instance.

ArrayList<Model> a2RetrievedList = a2.getList();
// You can also retrieve from AdapterTwo
```

Comment: This answer assumes you know `Singleton Pattern`

Comment: Thanks!! but i have solved it by set id(from restApi) as button id and ..get from v.getId();